# How to debug subprocess call in Python/Django

Tags: python, centos

In my Python/Django code I call `gdalbuildvrt` process. This process should create a .VRT file, but it does not. In order to check it, I write the subprocess output to a debug file. This is how I do it:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(["gdalbuildvrt", mosaic, folder], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout = process.communicate()[0]

with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "debug.txt"), 'w') as file:
    file.write('{}'.format(stdout) + " -> " + mosaic)
```

As a result I see this in debug.txt file:

```
b'0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.\n' -> /var/www/vwrapper/accent/accent/layers/raw/mosaic.vrt
```

So, as you can see the first part of debug statement says, that it'ok:

```
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

And the second part says, that `/var/www/vwrapper/accent/accent/layers/raw/mosaic.vrt` should be created. However, when I go to the target folder and refresh it, I see no mosaic.vrt file there. So, what may be wrong with that and how can I fix it? I should add that on Windows machine it's 100% ok, but on CentOS it does not.

Comment: Log `stderr` and the `.returncode`... that's where any problems will be.

Comment: @TemporalWolf. Would you be so kind to elaborate on this a little bit? You may make a complete answer, if you wish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
process = subprocess.Popen(["gdalbuildvrt", mosaic, folder], 
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
ret = process.returncode
```

or

```
process = subprocess.Popen(["gdalbuildvrt", mosaic, folder], 
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

which will redirect `stderr` to `stdout`.

Then log those two things:

All error logging should be on `stderr`, not `stdout`. And any return code will appear via [`process.returncode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode).

You could also probably use one of the higher processes, like `subprocess.check_call()`

Comment: Thanks! I've just checked it. stderr gets None value and ret gets 0 value. It seems like there are no errors, but still process does not do, what it should do. I really wonder, what may be wrong.

Comment: @Jacobian I made an edit. you have to make sure you add a pipe for `stderr` or redirect it to `stdout`

Comment: Fantastic! Now I see where the error was. Thank you so much!